# facebook Post to Wall Popup, replace "Write something...."

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I m publishing message on user wall using fb "Post to your wall" popup, it shows textarea where user can write message, I want to put custom text in that text area, right now it has a watermarker says "write something...", I need to replace that.

I m using this code:

```
function streamPublish(_message){
    FB.ui({
                    method: 'stream.publish',
                    message: 'this is a test message',
         },
    function(response) {

    });

}
```

thanks

Comment: Maybe you can change that text using javascript after the page loads?

Comment: thats textarea is in iframe, we can't do that using js

Comment: why this "this is a test message" is not appearing in that text area, then what is the use of message param

Comment: Why can't you? It should be fairly easy to access the DOM inside the IFrame as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I believe you can use:

```
user_message_prompt: 'Custom prompt'
```

So your code becomes:

```
function streamPublish(_message){
    FB.ui({
                    method: 'stream.publish',
                    message: 'this is a test message',
                    user_message_prompt: 'Custom prompt'
         },
    function(response) {

    });

}
```

(Source: http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui)

But be warned, this is deprecated, and won't be supported by the new API:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: $(function(){
     FB_RequireFeatures(['Connect'],function () {
      
      FB.init('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', null);
      FB.Connect.requireSession(function(){
       FB.Connect.streamPublish('sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd');
      },null,true);
     });
    });" this code was doing the job but feature loader is no more supported

Comment: You should be able to use it in your current code, I think? See edit above

Comment: I 've tested it nothing happen, I'm amused why the have provided the message param, its text is not display on wall, its no where

Comment: is there any other fb popup which I can use for this purpose

Comment: I'd recommend using the new feed dialog mentioned above https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ although, as I said, that won't let you change the placeholder

Comment: this is not working, I don't thing there is any workaround for this

Comment: Can we change it within the iframe, using JS?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook will lose the importance of the wall, if they allow us to do so.

Comment: I don't think so, we can put text, and if user don't like it he can change it before pressing share button

Comment: $(function(){ FB_RequireFeatures(['Connect'],function () { FB.init('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', null); FB.Connect.requireSession(function(){ FB.Connect.streamPublish('sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd'); },null,true); }); });" this code was doing the job but feature loader is no more supported

Comment: I agree, apps were never allowed to prefill this part of the message because it makes inauthentic communications and users don't like it - unfortunately apps were still prefilling this field against policy, so now it's just being changed so it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Can we change it within the iframe, using JS?